# Force a laptop to always use mobile versions of website when tethered to phone

Tags: mobile, browser, tethering

Sometimes when traveling, I'm forced to tether my laptop to my phone to get internet. When doing this, I would like my laptop browser to *use the mobile version of every website* I have to visit, if one is available. I understand that I could accomplish this by changing the *user-agent string*. When I stop tethering and return to using WiFi or ethernet I'd like the browser to go back to using the desktop version of websites.

I've tried using Developer Tools in various browsers to turn on emulation mode, but that still downloads the full desktop version of the site before switching it to the mobile version, which gobbles up my celular data plan (especially when traveling internationally) even if it's "unlimited" - which is what this is all about. So I'd like to have **only** the mobile version of the site load when tethered instead.

If it's possible, I'd like to do both things **automatically** without having to run terminal/shell scripts to modify .conf files or edit registry settings, etc.

I've done some searching and haven't found an answer. Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't helpful, but a lot of sites download both versions and it's entirely css for at what screen width that the mobile version is shown. You can see this by changing the width of your browser to this very question for an example.